# TextAsset returning null

Tags: c#, arrays, string, unity-game-engine

I have a script where I want to convert a text asset into a string array and then use that to modify PlayerPrefs. However, I keep getting a NullReferenceException Error during runtime on the second line in the code I have pasted below. I assume it's because I'm converting to the text asset into a string the wrong way. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please? Thanks

```
            TextAsset txt = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("SaveKeys1", typeof(TextAsset));

        string txtString = txt.text;



        char sep = (',');
        string[] keys = txtString.Split(sep);

        foreach(string key in keys)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey(key);
            Debug.Log(key);
        }
```

Comment: Have you perhaps made sure that `txt` is not equal to null?

Comment: with what you've shown, it's unclear. With Null-reference errors, you usually just need to debug a little deeper. Split out that first line into more separate lines, and debug to find exactly which part is returning `null`. Most likely thing, from assumptions and guesses, is that `txt` is null here. And only you will know why, by debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assume it's because I'm converting to the text asset into a string
>   the wrong way. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

The code:

```
TextAsset txt = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("SaveKeys1", typeof(TextAsset));
string txtString = txt.text;
```

is the correct way to do this. There is nothing wrong there and since you mentioned that the sceond line which is `string txtString = txt.text;` is causing an exception, there are two possible reasons for this.

**1**.Your file name is not spelt correctly. Please copy the file name directly from where it is located and paste the name directly into the `Resources.Load` function. Make sure **not** to include the extension(`.txt`,`.xml`...) in the function.

**2**.The SaveKeys1 file does not have the right extension. `TextAsset` only supports file extensions like `.txt`, `.html`, `.htm`, `.xml`, `.bytes`, `.json`, `.csv`, `.yaml`, and `.fnt`

**3**.`SaveKeys1` file is not placed in the right folder. For the `Resources.Load` function to work, the file must be placed in a folder called `Resources`. Usually, placing this file in any folder called `Resources` should work but just for testing purposes, create the folder in the `Assets/Resources` directory then put your SaveKeys1 file there. This should work.

Comment: I hadn't but the txt file in a folder called resources. It works now. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, which one fixed it?

Comment: I see. Spelling counts here when using [Unity's special folders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html). Happy coding!